# Magento Invoice Shipping Cost

Tags: shipping, invoice

I can get Shipping Cost from the order, but when I look at the invoices for the order only the first invoice gets the shipping cost.

How do I know if a invoice has a/the shipping cost attached?

Answer (score 0):

I found the attribute by looking in the table `sales_flat_invoice`

```
$shippingCost = $invoice->getShippingAmount();
```